# Creating a video upload form, what is a realistic file size limit?

Tags: video

My page is asking users to upload their photos and videos, but I want to limit the file size. What is a realistic size limit for short video (under  30 sec) shot on a iphone or android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chart below shows the approximate size of a 30 second video on various high end video-capable mobile handsets. (Adapted from [Engadget's video showdown here](http://www.engadget.com/2011/10/17/camera-showdown-iphone-4s-vs-iphone-4-galaxy-s-ii-nokia-n8-a/).)

```
                 iPhone 4S   iPhone 4   Galaxy S II   Nokia N8   Amaze 4G
30s movie size   97.5MB      40MB       49.25MB       32.5MB     38.25MB
```

Based on these stats, I'd suggest an upload limit of around 100MB.